# Installing print driver on Windows Azure VM

Tags: pdf, azure, pdf-generation

We have a native, stand alone Win32 application that we use to generate .PDF files. It is command line driven to take one of our data files in and generate a PDF file.   It works in conjunction with a print driver that is installed on the computer.

I know there are libraries for generating PDF files in .NET that we can use in Azure, however, there is specific type layout being carried out in our App that we must support, and that logic is not yet on the server side.  This is a short term cheat, before we port (or rewrite) our 20 year old type layout engine out of C/C++.  There is alot of code here with alot of complexity.

I see that we can now run native apps in Azure (yay).  However, my issue seems to be that this native application requires a print driver installed.  I have not been able to find any information about installing print driver in Azure worker role.

I found this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125385/printing-to-pdf-from-azure-worker-role.  The end result of this is to use a PDF library on Azure, which is not something that will work for us.

Also, I am aware that it is not the best use of a server to fire up a process to generate a PDF file everytime somebody wants to preview their data file in our web site. We are planning on cheating by showing the user the PDF, when they want to preview our proprietary data format in a browser.  This is Phase I of a project, and rewriting our 20 year old type layout engine in C# is going to take alot longer to accomplish, and we are talking about this (admitted hack) as a short term (in the bigger sense of things) measure.

How do I install a Print Driver in Windows Azure worker role?  Is it possible?  Are there any other options?

Many Thanks.

Comment: We ended up not pursuing this project after all, and did not put additional effort into testing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can do a command line, silent install of the Amyuni software that yms mentioned then you could run that as part of a startup task on your worker role, probably with elevated permissions.  People use startup tasks to do all sorts of things and many of them have written blog posts about it or answer questions about them here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=azure%20startup%20task%20install&submit=search), but a good place to start would be the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx).

Comment: This is good reference.  Thank you.  I knew that I could run a native process.  I was unsure about the print driver install.

Answer (score 1):

This may help: [Amyuni PDF Converter](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfconverter/features) is a PDF printer driver with an API exposed as a COM interface and as a net. assembly that allows you to silently install and uninstall the driver programmatically. This can be done by using the methods [PDFDriverInit](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_Document_Converter/Printer_Installation_and_Activation/Methods/PDFDriverInit,_HTMLDriverInit,_RTFDriverInit.htm) and [DriverEnd](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_Document_Converter/Printer_Installation_and_Activation/Methods/DriverEnd.htm) from your application.

Once your application installs the driver, you can [print to PDF using a memory stream as destination and upload it to a Microsoft Azure Blob Storage](http://blog.amyuni.com/?p=1693).

There are 2 ways of installing Amyuni PDF Converter:

1- Using the installation program provided with the package.
2- Copying the dll files to their corresponding folders and then calling the method DriverInit.

The complete process is explained here:
[Using the Developer Version of the Amyuni Document Converter](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_Document_Converter/Using_the_Developer_Amyuni_Converter.htm)

About your specific scenario, if you have an application that uses Amyuni PDF Converter, then there is indeed a printer driver that should be installed with it. Your application could be installing the driver every time it is launched and removing it when it is closed, or it could be installing it only during the installation of your program.

If you do not have the source code of this application but you still have the license information of the library provided by Amyuni, you could try building a small application or batch script that just takes care of the installation process. You can contact [Amyuni support](http://www.amyuni.com/en/support/getsupport/) for a link to the latest build of the version you are using.

You mentioned that you are using Windows Azure VM, so I am assuming that [you have administrative rights](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/) on the virtual system and that you can connect to it using remote desktop and run any kind of applications.

*Usual disclaimer applies*

Comment: Hi yms, thank you for your quick response.  We actually are using Amyuni.  However, it seems to require a print driver installed.  When I go to Start | Devices and Printers in Windows, one of the printers displayed has our app name in it.  When selected, Model is set to "Amyuni Document Converter 400".  It seems that this must be installed on the computer first.  Is this a wrong assumption?  Our native app can already generate a PDF file (which uses your library).  We just want to run that App in Azure, which I can't find a way to install the print driver "in the cloud".  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail.  This is useful, and it will require additional research on my part.  This definitely covers the side of the equation relating to getting Amyuni to work without an installed printer drive.